# Table is at the bottom of the frame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have coded up a simple `swing gui`. However, my problem is that my table is on the bottom of my page. I would like to have with **some space below my buttons** and also more space down to the bottom. Here is a short program, what I am doing:

```
public class minimumExample extends JFrame {

    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private FilteredTabPanel filteredTabPanel;

    public void createTabBar() {

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        filteredTabPanel = new FilteredTabPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Test", filteredTabPanel.createLayout());

        add(tabbedPane);
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

    private void makeLayout() {

        setTitle("Test App");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
        createTabBar();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void start() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                makeLayout();   
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        minimumExample ex = new minimumExample();
        ex.start();
    }

    public class FilteredTabPanel extends JPanel {

        private JPanel selectionArea;
        private JLabel lCity;
        private JComboBox cityBox;
        private JTable filterTable;
        String[] columnNames = {"Cities"};
        String[][] data = {
                {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"LA"}, {"LA"},{"Columbia"},{"DC"},{"DC"},{"DC"},{"DC"},{"DC"},{"DC"}
        };

        private JScrollPane scrollPane;

        public JPanel createLayout() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            //add panels to the layout
            panel.add(addButtons());    
            panel.add(showTable());

            repaint();
            revalidate();

            return panel;
        }

        public JPanel addButtons(){

            selectionArea = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

            lCity = new JLabel("City");

            String[] fillings = {"NY", "LA", "Columbia", "DC"};
            cityBox = new JComboBox(fillings);

            cityBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                private String cityFilter;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    //2. get data
                    cityFilter = cityBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
            });

            selectionArea.add(lCity);
            selectionArea.add(cityBox);

            selectionArea.repaint();

            return selectionArea;
        }

        private JScrollPane showTable() {

            filterTable =new JTable(data, columnNames);
            filterTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(filterTable);

            scrollPane.repaint();
            scrollPane.validate();

            return scrollPane;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the page looks like:

[image]

Any recommendations how to fix that?

Comment: Add the table to the layout and set it to BorderLayout.CENTER. See the docs on layouts using BorderLayout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Comment: @Katana24 Thx for your answer! Where do you mean that I should add it? I really appreciate a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is nesting simple layout managers 
to create your layout. I think that the official Swing tutorial
is doing a disservice to the programmers by introducing these
simple layout managers first. I recommend to avoid them and
invest some time into more powerful managers.
`FlowLayout`, `BorderLayout` and `Gridlayout` are really very
simple managers but they cannot do much.

I recommend to use these two managers:

- `MigLayout`
- `GroupLayout`

(JGoodies's `FormLayout` is also a good option.)

Not only are these managers more powerful, they also cope
with more advanced requirements where others fail. (Resolution 
independence, adherence to OS design principles etc.)

Before I present my two code examples, I want to say a few
points to your code. You are unnecessarily calling `repaint()`
and `revalidate()` methods.

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
```

Specifying sizes in pixels is not portable. You better rely on
the `pack()` method.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

The `JFrame's` default layout manager (more precisely its content pane's)
is `BorderLayout`. Therefore, this line is not needed.

The following two examples are solutions with `MigLayout` and `GroupLayout`.

**MigLayout solution**

`MigLayout` is a third-party layout manager, so you need to download and
add additional jar to your project.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutEx extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox cityBox;
    private JTable filterTable;

    public MigLayoutEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        add(tabbedPane);

        filterTable = createTable();
        cityBox = createCityBox();

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout(""));
        pnl.add(new JLabel("City"), "split 2");
        pnl.add(cityBox, "wrap");

        pnl.add(new JScrollPane(filterTable));

        tabbedPane.addTab("Test", pnl);
        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JTable createTable() {

        String[] columnNames = {"Cities"};
        String[][] data = {
            {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"LA"}, {"LA"}, {"Columbia"},
            {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        return table;
    }

    private JComboBox createCityBox() {

        String[] fillings = {"NY", "LA", "Columbia", "DC"};
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(fillings);

        return box;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutEx ex = new MigLayoutEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: MigLayout example]

**GroupLayout solution**

`GroupLayout` is a built-in layout manager, no need to add additional jars.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class GroupLayoutEx extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox cityBox;
    private JTable filterTable;

    public GroupLayoutEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pnl);
        pnl.setLayout(gl);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        add(tabbedPane);

        JLabel cityLbl = new JLabel("City");
        filterTable = createTable();
        JScrollPane spane = new JScrollPane(filterTable);
        cityBox = createCityBox();

        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(cityLbl)
                        .addComponent(cityBox))
                .addComponent(spane)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(cityLbl)
                        .addComponent(cityBox))
                .addComponent(spane)
        );

        tabbedPane.addTab("Test", pnl);
        pack();

        setTitle("GroupLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JTable createTable() {

        String[] columnNames = {"Cities"};
        String[][] data = {
            {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"NY"}, {"LA"}, {"LA"}, {"Columbia"},
            {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}, {"DC"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        return table;
    }

    private JComboBox createCityBox() {

        String[] fillings = {"NY", "LA", "Columbia", "DC"};
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(fillings);

        return box;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GroupLayoutEx ex = new GroupLayoutEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I recommend to study both managers and to choose your favourite.

Comment: This is a much better and more complete answer than mine - accept this one

Comment: Thanks for acknowledment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you refactor your code as it's hard to follow as it is - for example the `showTable()` method could be renamed `getTable()` as you're returning the table that you have created.

From my comment - add the table to the layout and set it to `BorderLayout.CENTER`. See the docs on layouts [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

What I mean is that you'd layout your components onto the BorderLayout based on their respective location.

You want the table to inhabit the center which will leave the `SOUTH` (otherwise known as `PAGE_END`) open to its own component, i.e. the space.

```
JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel("Button");        // Add your logic to create the button panel
frame.add(btnPanel , BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // Or BorderLayout.NORTH

JPanel tblPanel = new JPanel("Table");         // Table panel
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER );       // Inhabits center

JPanel southPanel = new JPanel("South Panel");
frame.add( southPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Comment: From 1.4 it is best to use `LINE_START`/`LINE_END` & `PAGE_START`/`PAGE_END` since they are localized to the user language.  E.G. `LINE_START`/`LINE_END` swap sides between a machine with default language of English (left-to-right text) & Arabic (right-to-left text).